# adding webview in the end of Textview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webview, textview

I have textView with some content. The content is dynamic. I need to add to TextView in the end of content webview. When I am adding via addsubview it always put web view content on different places in TextView.

I tried to play with CGRect but it didn't improved this situation

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, textView.contentSize.height+textView.frame.size.height-100, 250, 160)];
```

How I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in setting the frames of the web view. Try this:

```
UIWebView *sampleWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.SampleTextView.contentSize.height, self.SampleTextView.frame.size.width , self.SampleTextView.frame.size.height)];
```

Output will be like this(This what you required i guess):

[image]

Comment: I have TextView with Articles. every article has different content size. This textView situated on scrollview with other content. I need to put video right after article.

Comment: U didn't mention scrollview and all in the query.as u said u have placed on text view and one web view with in a scroll view. u need to set the web view immediate to text view right?